# How to sum up all nodes in this scala fold_tree function

Tags: scala, fold

I am a beginner with scala. I have been given a fold_tree_preorder function that implements the higher order function fold on a binary tree. The tree, node and leaf definitions are below

```
 abstract class Tree[+A]
  case class Leaf[A](value: A) extends Tree[A]
  case class Node[A](value: A, left: Tree[A], right: Tree[A]) extends Tree[A]
```

This is the function I have been given

```
  def fold_tree_preorder [Z,A](f:(Z,A)=>Z) (z:Z) (t:Tree[A]) : Z =
    t match {
      case Leaf(value) => f(z, value)
      case Node(value , lt, rt) => {
            val z1 = f(z,value)
            val z2 = fold_tree_preorder (f) (z1) (lt)
            fold_tree_preorder (f) (z2) (rt)

          }
      }
```

I am not sure how to actually call this function. I am trying to do something like the following:

```
def count_tree [A](t:Tree[A]) : Int =
    fold_tree_preorder[A,A=>A]((z,a)=>(z+a))(0)(t)
```

But I am getting errors like type mismatch error. I don't think the parameters themselves are correct either, but I'm not even sure how to test what the output would look like because I can't figure out the correct way of calling the fold_tree_preorder function. How can I input the correct syntax to call this function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`z` is the `fold_tree_preorder` function is the output type you are expecting which is `Int`

Use the function like below

assuming that `count_tree` counts number of nodes of the tree

```
def count_tree [A](t:Tree[A]) : Int =
    fold_tree_preorder[Int, A]((z,a) => z + 1 )(0)(t)
```

Just add `1` to the z on visiting a node to count number of nodes

Comment: Ok, I understand now. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
def fold_tree_preorder [Z,A](f:(Z,A)=>Z) (z:Z) (t:Tree[A]) : Z
```

The first argument is `f`, is function that takes the result so far (of type `Z`) and the value contained in your tree `A`)

```
 def count_tree [A](t:Tree[A]) : Int
```

In your function your promising to return an `Int` based on a tree of which you don't know the element type, parameterized as `A`. This leads you to add an `Int` to an `A`.

Summing and counting are different things, if you decide to count the number of values, you do not need to know anything about `A`. If you decide to sum the values, you need to know you have a `+` operator defined for `A`.

You might need to learn more about scala's types.
https://twitter.github.io/scala_school/advanced-types.html